Trying to get pyautogui to press "'" not working
So basically, I'm having it go to this window which has my game on it. I'm having it click the ' bind but for some reason it won't. I've tried swapping the keybind for / and it works all fine. Maybe my code is wrong?
import pyautogui
import time

x, y = pyautogui.position()

pyautogui.moveTo(957, 525, duration=0)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.click()

pyautogui.press("'")

pyautogui.typewrite(';cmdbar', interval=0)

pyautogui.press("enter")

This was supposed to do it all, but for some reason it does everything but hit the ' key.
